# Subtract two dates (set in JLabels)

Tags: java, swing

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                            
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dateOnly = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");
    label1.setText(dateOnly.format(cal.getTime()));
    label2.getText();
}
```

questions:
  how do you remove/parse a date from a JLabel?
  how do you subtract 2 dates?

label1 input value is  today date.26-09-2014.
  label2 input value is 26-10-2014.

How can i get the answer: "30 days" in  jtextfield.

Comment: You can use [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html) and [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html).

Answer (score 0):

With joda library:

```
// parsing

DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime(2014, 9, 26, 1, 0);
DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime(2014, 9, 26, 0, 0));

DateTimeFormatter dtfOut = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
System.out.println(dtfOut.print(dateTime1));
System.out.println(dtfOut.print(dateTime2));

// substracting
System.out.println(Days.daysBetween(dateTime1, dateTime2).getDays() + " days");
```

Answer (score 0):

Get your dates and Parse the data in the following format

```
Date date1,date2=null;

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

date1= format.parse(fromDateValue);
date2= format.parse(toDateValue);
```

The difference of two dates will be in milliseconds which needs to be handled using a long variable

```
long subDateValue = date2.getTime()-date1.getTime();
long subValueinDays = subDateValue/(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) //convert milliseconds into seconds and then into days
System.out.println("Days Difference between" +fromDateValue + "and" +toDateValue +"is" +subValueinDays + "Days");
```